# Why there is no BEGIN TRANSACTION statment in SQL Profiler

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I have two POCO objects, Customer and CustomerAddress as follows.

```
public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.CustomerAddresses = new HashSet<CustomerAddress>();
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public byte Gender { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

public partial class CustomerAddress
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public byte AddressType { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

I am creating a new Customer object as follows.

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
            cust.ID = 9;
            cust.LastName = "Ross";
            cust.FirstName = "Taylor";
            cust.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
            cust.Gender = 0;

            CustomerAddress custAdd = new CustomerAddress();
            custAdd.ID = 9;
            custAdd.Customer = cust;
            custAdd.AddressType = 0;
            custAdd.Street = "1 Main Street";
            custAdd.City = "Princeton";
            custAdd.State = "CA";
            custAdd.Country = "USA";

            DbConnection MyContext = new DbConnection(); ;
            MyContext.Customers.Add(cust);
            MyContext.CustomerAddresses.Add(custAdd);
            MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

I launch SQL Profiler.  When this data is been saved, there are two insert script run against database, one for Customer and other for CustomerAddress. But my confusion is that I don't see any BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT statements in SQL Profiler. If for some reason insert script for CustomerAddress fail, I would like whole transaction to fail and I am not sure if I will get it without a BEGIN TRANSACTION. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you including the Transaction Events in your trace via the "Events Selection" tab?

Comment: I don't have any filter. Based on that I assume yes but let me know if this is not correct.

Comment: You are not correct. Transaction Events are not included by default.

Comment: [See screenshot here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EgK8t.png). Are the relevant events selected?

Comment: hmm, I am not getting this view. When I launch profiler, on trace properties I am using Standard (default) template. Is this what you have as well?

Comment: OK, I found it. Yeah I didn't had that selected. After selecting transaction, I do see it now. Thanks for your help. Not sure if I can mark your comment as answer.